# Append a jQuery variable to a click event handler function

Tags: jquery, highcharts

UPDATED:

The complete script.

I have a script that processes some Json data to produce a graph using HighCharts. The Json data has three elements:

```
[{"name":"Room","data":[343,405,406,407]},
{"name":"Temp C","data":[50,50,50,50]},
{"name":"UniqueID","data": 
    ["GLAZH03431464336298",
     "GLAZH04051465483111",
     "GLAZH04061464783558",
     "GLAZH04071465484869"]
}]
```

In my script I have the following:

```
$(function() {
    var categories = [];
    var data = [];
    var uniqueid = [];
    var chart;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("chart.php", function(json) {
            $.each(json, function(i, el) {
                if (el.name == "Room")
                    categories = el.data;
                else if (el.name == "UniqueID") {
                    uniqueid = el.data;
                } else data.push(el);
            });

            console.log(uniqueid, "UniqueID");

            $('#container1').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'line',
                    zoomType: 'x',
                    marginTop: 40,
                    marginRight: 30,
                    marginBottom: 50,
                    plotBackgroundColor: '#FCFFC5'
                },
                title: {
                    text: '<?php echo $_SESSION['
                    _amember_user ']['
                    hotel '];?> Room hot water temperatures ',
                    x: -20, //center
                    style: {
                        fontFamily: 'Tahoma',
                        color: '#000000',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        fontSize: '10px'
                    }
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Zoom: hold cursor over chart, hold left mouse button and drag, release button',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: categories,

                    labels: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                },

                yAxis: {
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: '<?php echo $row_Rooms['
                        Hotmax '];?>',
                        color: '#FF0000',
                        width: 1,
                        zIndex: 10,
                        label: {
                            text: 'Maximum <?php echo $row_Rooms['
                            Hotmax '];?> °C',
                            align: 'center',
                            x: -10,
                            y: -5,
                            style: {
                                color: '#FF0000'
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        value: '<?php echo $row_Rooms['
                        HotMin '];?>',
                        color: '#0000CC',
                        width: 1,
                        zIndex: 10,
                        label: {
                            text: 'Minimum <?php echo $row_Rooms['
                            HotMin '];?> °C',
                            align: 'center',
                            x: -10,
                            y: 20,
                            style: {
                                color: '#0000CC'
                            }
                        }
                    }],

                    showFirstLabel: false,
                    lineColor: '#999',
                    lineWidth: 0.2,
                    tickColor: '#666',
                    tickWidth: 1,
                    tickLength: 2,
                    tickInterval: 10,
                    gridLineColor: '#ddd',
                    title: {
                        text: 'Temperature °C',
                        style: {
                            fontFamily: 'Tahoma',
                            color: '#000000',
                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                            fontSize: '10px'
                        }
                    },
                },

                legend: {
                    enabled: false,
                    itemStyle: {
                        font: '11px Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif',
                        color: '#000000'
                    },
                    itemHoverStyle: {
                        color: '#000000'
                    },
                    itemHiddenStyle: {
                        color: '#444'
                    }
                },

                colors: [
                    '#009900',

                ],

                plotOptions: {
                    style: {
                        textShadow: false
                    },
                    column: {
                        color: '#ff00ff'
                    },
                    series: {

                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        point: {
                            events: {
                                click: function() {
                                    window.top.location.href = "water.php?room="
                                    this.uniqueid;
                                    console.log(uniqueid);
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false,
                            rotation: 0,
                            color: '#000000',
                            align: 'center',
                            //format: '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
                            y: 0, // 10 pixels down from the top
                            style: {
                                textShadow: false,
                                fontSize: '10px',
                                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                            }
                        }
                    }

                },

                tooltip: {
                    enabled: true,
                    crosshairs: [false, true],
                    positioner: function() {
                        return {
                            x: 5,
                            y: -5
                        };
                    },
                    shadow: false,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)',

                    formatter: function() {
                        return 'Room: <b>' + this.x +
                            '</b> is <b>' + this.y + ' °C</b>';
                    }
                },

                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },

                series: data
            });
        });
    });
});
```

What I want to do is pass the "uniqueid" and append it to the end of a URL in a event click like:

```
click: function() {
    window.top.location.href = "water.php?room=" + this.uniqueid;
}
```

If I use "console.log(uniqueid, "UniqueID");" in the script and check the content in a debugger, I see:

```
Array ["GLAZH03431464336298", 
        "GLAZH04051465483111", 
        "GLAZH04061464783558", 
        "GLAZH04071465484869"]
```

My question is how can I append the content of uniqueid to the end of my URL for the click event. Whatever I do I can't get this to work.

Comment: Is uniqueId only going to be one value that you need to refer to, or do you need unique id stored separately for each value in the json response?

Comment: Hi agmcleod, yes, uniqueid needs stored separately for each value. Depending on which point in the graph is selected, the URL is run with the "room=?uniqueid and is then processed by another scripts using "$_GET['uniqueid'].

Comment: ah okay. Given you're not attaching uniqueid or categories to an object, nor do they have `var`, they will be global variables. That's bad. If you can update your post to show what you're doing with the data array in the $.each call, and how you're binding the click, i might be able to further assist.

Comment: Hi agmcleod, Many thanks. I have updated the Post with more detail.

Comment: the `xAxis` and `series` bits are not valid javascript on their own, must be something else you're obscuring from the example. Essentially what needs to happen is in your $.each of the data from the request, you need to map each unique id to a click event. Can either register the click event with `$('selector here').on('click', function() {window.top.location.href = "water.php?room=" + el.data})`, or if you need to do it outside the loop, store the unique id inside a collection you can use later.

Comment: Hi agmcleod, sorry  to come back. I have updated the post with the complete script. I was trying to keep it short but you are correct you need to see the whole script. Again many thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114761/discussion-between-agmcleod-and-dcjones).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wiltsc/a8pp300g/3/). Refer to Javascript line#140 `console.log(this.uniqueid);`,  this is printing `undefined` in browser console that's why your code is not working..

The problem you have now is that you are not able to link a temperature to a uniqueId in your Highcharts. Refer to [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wiltsc/a8pp300g/4/) line#38, I'm trying to construct following JSON and set it to `Highcharts.series.data` at line#201. By doing so , I'm able to get the value of `temperature`, `room` and `uniqueId` of each point in line#156.

```
[{
    y: 50,
    uniqueid: 'GLAZH03431464336298'
}, {
    y: 71.5,
    uniqueid: 'GLAZH04051465483111'
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the datasets in your result will always be the same order & length, build your data object instead merging those together:

```
$.getJSON("chart.php", function(json) {
    $.each(json, function(i, el) {
        var collection = [];
        if (el.name == "Room" || el.name == "UniqueID")
            collection = el.data;
        } else {
            collection = el;
        }

        for (var j = 0; j < collection.length; j++) {
            data[j] = data[j] || {};
            data[j][(el.name || "y").toLowerCase()] = collection[j];
        }
    });

    // high charts code
});
```

Then in your click event, see if you can grab the properties room & uniqueid. I haven't used highcharts, so im not sure what properties it would persist for you in the click event. This is where you'll want to set a breakpoint, and inspect the object.